# How to design the bootstrap columns dynamically in php

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hello i am building a project where i have the requirement as of showing the columns like as shown in figure but i am not able to iterate the columns, i am also pasting the codes of how much i have done till now. Please help me how can I achieve this.

[image]

```
<section id="services" class="ls section_intro_overlap columns_padding_0 columns_margin_0 container_padding_0 hidden-md hidden-lg" style="padding:15px 0 30px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row flex-wrap v-center-content">
            <?php 
$sl_rp="select * from $tb_products where status='active' order by id DESC" ; 
$res_rp=m ysqli_query($conn,$sl_rp); if($res_rp){ 
$nums_rp=m ysqli_num_rows($res_rp); if($nums_rp>0){ 
$i=0; 
while($rows_rp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_rp)){ 
$productid = $rows_rp['id'].'/'.'asdfghjklqweretyuiophjgbcfhdgvsf'; $t_encode = base64_encode($productid); $i++; 
?>
            <div class="col-xs-<?php if($i==3) { echo '12'; }else{ echo '6'; } ?> to_animate" data-animation="fadeInUp">
                <div class="teaser card-<?php echo $i; ?> transp with_padding big-padding margin_0">
                    <div class="media xxs-media-left">
                        <div class="media-left media-middle">
                            <div class="teaser_icon size_small big_wrapper">
                                <?php if($i==1){ ?>
                                <img src="barbie_images/icon-glos.png" class="img-responsive img-center mar-top-5">
                                <?php }else if($i==2){ ?>
                                <img src="barbie_images/icon-bw.png" class="img-responsive img-center mar-top-5">
                                <?php }else if($i==3){ ?>
                                <img src="barbie_images/icon-clr.png" class="img-responsive img-center mar-top-5">
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body media-middle">
                            <h4 class="text-white"><?php echo $rows_rp['pname']; ?></h4>
                            <a href="fill-details.php?product=<?php echo $t_encode; ?>" class="btn btn-default text-capitalize card_buttons">Buy Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } } } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: use flex to get it done

Comment: how??? Can you please be more specific

Comment: create a class or div name, add `col-md-6` to that div or class and the use flex to get the actual results as in pic

Comment: sorry @dean i got my ans $i % 3 == 0, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think I know the answer, you can use

```
<div class="col-xs-<?php if($i % 3 == 0) { echo '12'; }else{ echo '6'; } ?> to_animate" data-animation="fadeInUp">
```

So, what actually is happening when remainder comes 0 you can use 12 (i.e. - col-xs-6) and else you can 6 (i.e. - col-xs-6)